# Neo4j How to create relationships after ingesting data

Tags: java, nosql, neo4j, relationship

Say I have a csv file where one of the columns is unix timestamp. It is not sorted on that, but following those in order could be a useful relationship. When I want that, I could use ORDER BY, but adding relationship pointers should be faster right, and make use of the NOSQL? Do I have to sort this and add the relationship as I ingest, or can I do it after a query?

After I run the first query and get a subset back:

```
    result = engine.execute(START...WHERE...ORDER BY time)
```

Can I then go through results adding this relationship like:

```
    prev.createRelationshipTo(next, PRECEDES);
```

I tried two different ways using foreach or iterator and both had runtime errors casting a string to a Node:

```
    for (Map<String, Object>row : result) {
        String n = (String) row.values().iterator().next();
        System.out.println(n);
    }

    Iterator<Node> nodes = result.columnAs("n.chosen");
    if (nodes.hasNext()) {
        Node prev = nodes.next();
        while (nodes.hasNext()) {
            Node n = nodes.next();
            prev.createRelationshipTo(n, null);
            prev = n;
        }
    }
```

Also, there is the edge case of two rows having the same timestamp. I don't care about the order that is chosen, but I want it to not break the relation chain.

Comment: Maybe I can run a cipher query like:

        START n=node(*) MATCH p.time < p2.time and not exist (p.time < p3.time and p3.time < p2.time) CREATE p-[:precedes]->p2;